# method ends before receiving data from Combine Future Publisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have such code:

```
import Cocoa
import Combine

func prepareURLRequest(for url: URL) -> URLRequest {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var token = "token"

    print("start value: \(token)")

    let subscription = Token()
    subscription.getToken()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
        print("subscription completed")
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        token = value
        print("value received: \(token)")
    })

    print("new value: \(token)")

    // attach received token to request
    return request
}


class Token {
    let token = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()

    func verify() -> Bool {
        // TODO: Token verification logic
        Bool.random()
    }

    func getToken() -> AnyPublisher<String,Never> {
        return Future<String, Never> { promise in
            if self.verify() {
                let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://avatars.io/twitter/twostraws")!)
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    print("Data Task started")
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error \(error)")

                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        preconditionFailure("data error")
                    }
                    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                        preconditionFailure("response error")
                    }

                    print("data task received response with code: \(response.statusCode)")
                    promise(.success("\(response.statusCode)"))
                }.resume()
            } else {
                print("keychain path")
                sleep(2)
                promise(.success("kwychain path success"))
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "http://avatars.io/twitter/twostraws")!
let request = prepareURLRequest(for: url)
```

code should attach sinked token to prepared request object. Now the only `verify -> false path` returns data in required order. When I try `verify -> true` path data is sinked after prepareURLRequest ends it's life.

How to fix this to have both paths result with proper order (and token being updated before prepareURLRequest method ends?

Comment: You have too many different entities named “token” in your code: a local property named `token` of type `String`, the `String` value `"token"`, a class named `Token`, a property in that class named `token`, and the value returned by the `getToken` method.  It's very confusing. Perhaps you could give them more meaningful names?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you didn't wrap the Future with a Deferred. Your code is written expecting that the API calls won't be made until demand is requested, but that's not quite how Future works.

As soon as a Future is created, it invokes it's underlying async API call to present - and you're using a PassthroughSubject above means it's already done it's call by the time you have a subscriber asking for data. The best way to solve this is to wrap `Future` in a `Deferred` publisher, which waits to create it until a subscription asks for data.

There's [an example of wrapping Future with Deferred in the Future reference page of](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-future) [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine), plus more information about how Future works and what other operators do with it.